# php- find duplicate and sort by array property

Tags: php, sorting, large-data, array-unique

I have a large associative array of products. i want to check if there are **duplicate** products then get product with **low price**.

I can use *array_unique* and *array_count_values* to find duplicate records, but I don't know how to handle sorting part.

array properties:

- product_id (unique)
- title
- price

**sample data**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1111
            [title] => Product 1
            [price] => 140
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2222
            [title] => Product 2
            [price] => 66
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1111
            [title] => Product 1 A
            [price] => 123
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3333
            [title] => Product 3
            [price] => 37.4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 4444
            [title] => Product 4
            [price] => 10.5
        )

)
```

product 1 is duplicated so there will be one record against product 1 and with low price should be kept.

**output should be like**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1111
            [title] => Product 1
            [price] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2222
            [title] => Product 2
            [price] => 66
        )  

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3333
            [title] => Product 3
            [price] => 37.4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 4444
            [title] => Product 4
            [price] => 10.5
        )

)
```

Comment: Show a sample of the array.

Comment: ^ and what you've tried

Comment: What counts as duplicate? You said `product_id` is unique.

Comment: @HtmHell product_id should be unique, i can use this property to check if product is duplicated or not.

Comment: @user3554045 After removing duplicates do you want to sort the array? if so, by what value?

Comment: @HtmHell  at the time of removing i want to sort duplicate products by price

Comment: I can't post an answer, but this code should do: `$tempArray = [];
    
    foreach ($array as &$v) {
        if (!isset($tempArray[$v['product_id']]) || $tempArray[$v['product_id']]['price'] > $v['price'])
            $tempArray[$v['product_id']] =& $v;
    }
    
    $array = array_values($tempArray);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create an array that has only unique product_id's showing only the lowest price for each product_id:

```
$products_lowestprices = [];

foreach ( $products AS &$product ) {

  if ( isset( $products_lowestprices[ $product[ 'product_id' ] ] ) ) {
    if ( $products_lowestprices[ $product[ 'product_id' ] ][ 'price' ] > $product[ 'price' ] ) {
      $products_lowestprices[ $product[ 'product_id' ] ] = $product;
    }
  } else {
    $products_lowestprices[ $product[ 'product_id' ] ] = $product;
  }

}

$products_lowestprices = array_values( $products_lowestprices );
```

Comment: @user3554045 Glad I could help!